# How to get any public Instagram profile information (such as posts info) through Instagram APIs?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I'm building an application that analyze some profiles posts to get information from them (such as descriptions, likes, image URL, ecc). So i need access through Instagram API to these information related to any public business account.

Is this possible?

I'm trying with:

```
graph.facebook.com/**my_id**?fields=business_discovery.username(**name_of_the_account**){media_count}&access_token=**access-token_of_my_application**
```